# Navit in FB causes SDL init -1

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, navigation, framebuffer, sdl

I'm trying to compile Navit for Rpi3 with Buildroot image (WPE Framework included). There is only WPE Framework running on startup (no x server) therefore I would like to display Navit using framebuffer.
I know there is support for this. I have configured Navit as follow:
[Navit Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZ3O.png)
but I'm not able to run it anyway. There is following error. I've installed SDL from buildroot.

> error:graphics_sdl:graphics_sdl_new:SDL_Init failed -1

Can anybody point me how should I set up Navit to run smothly withoutusing X Server (with cooperation with WPE)? It's a pitty that Navit doen't allow to display layout directly in a Web Browser...

Answer (score 0):

t turned out that Navit is very quiet about SDL error messages. -1 Error is just very general information... I had to recompile Navit sources and add SDL_GetError() function to code to find out what is a real reason. The problem was missing mouse. I don't need it so I had to set up:

> export SDL_NOMOUSE=1